# reversing *ngFor array causes flickering

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I've stumbled upon a really odd issue. I'm building an Ionic app with Angular, and I have an `ngFor` with a `reverse` on it, the weird thing is, it works fantastically if I run it on my device but as soon as I add the `--prod` variable to run it in production state the `reverse` causes intense flickering. Essentially, it changes between the `reverse` state and the un-reversed every second... It works perfectly when it's not in production.

Here is a gif:

[image]

The 19 hours is what I want to show first, the 15 days is what I want to show last..

Here is my code for fetching from firebase:

```
goToNew() {
  this.zone = new NgZone({});
  this.postFeed = new Array();
  this.feedCounter = new Array();

  this.database.database.ref('/posts/'+this.locationId)
  .orderByChild('created')
  .limitToLast(10)
  .once('value', (snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach(child => {
        this.feedCounter.push(child.val());
        this.postFeed.push(child.val());

        return false;
    });
  });
}
```

and here is my HTML:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let post of postFeed.reverse; let i = index">
  <div *ngIf="i > 0 && i % 10 == 0" class="pageIndicator">
    <div class="seperator"></div>
    <div class="pageNumb">Page {{i / 10 + 1}}</div>
    <div class="seperator"></div>
  </div>
  <post [postData]="post"></post>
</ng-container>
```

I've also tried `this.postFeed.reverse()` within the `goToNow()` function but it does the exact same thing. I also tried `this.postFeed.unshift()` instead of `push` but that didn't work at all.

So as I say, this works 100% when I run my app as:

`ionic cordova run android --device`

but as soon as I do:

`ionic cordova run android --device --prod`

It freaks out. Removing `reverse` works, but that's not how I want to display the array.

What am I doing wrong? Is this a bug with Ionic/Angular/Something else? I have *no* idea why this doesn't work with `--prod`.

Comment: your gif is not showing the full picture - can you adjust it a bit?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it is caused by `postFeed.reverse()` which **changes itself and return itself**.

which means,

```
var tmp = [1,2,3]
var tmp2 = tmp.reverse()
console.log(tmp) // [3,2,1]
console.log(tmp2) // [3,2,1]
console.log(tmp===tmp2) // true
```

Last statement in the above code means `tmp.reverse()` do not returns new array but **itself**.

So, in your **.html** code, `postFeed.reverse()` returns **reversed itself**. As changes occur, `postFeed.reverse()` is executed repeatly. Then, view sholud also change because content changed. Thus, view must be flickering.

You should use this kind of code (Just for example, it is not efficient.)
`postFeed.concat().reverse()`